# How do I display a matching element equal to a given value in a dataframe with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to display the name of a country by searching for the biggest difference between the amount of Gold in "Gold" and the amount of Gold in "Gold.1". Now I am unsure how to display the name of the country (column 1) when calculating this difference.

```
def answer_two():
for country in df :
        valx = df["Gold"]
        valy = df["Gold.1"]
        valAns = abs(valx - valy)
        if df.iloc[country] > df.iloc[country-1]:
            ans = valAns
    return ans

print(answer_two())
```

My plan was to calculate valAns and then maybe get the index of country and then return that name...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that would assist in answering your question. This (`idxmax()`) will return the index of the greatest value in a Series, which as you can see in this case is the difference between columns `one` and `two`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()   
df['one'] = [1,2,3]
df['two'] = [2,5,8]

df['diff'] = df.two - df.one

max_value_index = df['diff'].idxmax()
```